# Why doesn't the div content update in dash / plotly?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I tried using a div containing various elements with which the user can interact and then pass the entire div element as a `State` to a function to be able to read all of the various inputs.

However, it seems that the div isn't getting updated. I wrote a small programme which shows the problem below:

```
import dash                                                                     
import dash_html_components as html                                             
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State                              
import dash_core_components as dcc                                              


app = dash.Dash(__name__)                                                       
app.css.append_css({                                                            
    'external_url': ('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/'                      
                     'bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css')                   
    })                                                                          


app.layout = html.Div(                                                          
    className='container-fluid',                                                
    children=[                                                                  
        html.Div(id='test', children=[                                          
            html.Button(id='btn', children='Press me'),                         
            dcc.Input(id='inp', value='asdf')                                   
        ]),                                                                     
        html.Div(id='out')]                                                     
)                                                                               


@app.callback(                                                                  
    Output('out', 'children'),                                                  
    [Input('btn', 'n_clicks')],                                                 
    [State('test', 'children')]                                                 
)                                                                                  
def update(n, div):                                                                
    print(div) # This div always contains the string 'asdf' even if I type something else in the Input field


app.run_server(debug=True, port=8888)
```

I know that in this simple case I could just have the `State` depend on the value property of the id='inp' however each of these is generated dynamically so I thought I'd create whatever I create in the div and then pass the div and parse it (which I have code for). The only problem is I can't get the div to update!

EDIT:

There seems to be confusion as to the issue. I'm trying to get the value of the `Input` box through the parent div and passing the children. However, that didn't work! I've added a comment in the code to explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could possibly be a bug, as the `'value'` property of the `dcc.Input` seems to revert back to default and not persist the changes to the input value. However, it appears that you can force the changes to persist by passing `State('inp', 'value')` as an additional input parameter to your callback function:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    className='container-fluid',
    children=[
        html.Div(id='test', children=[
            html.Button(id='btn', children='Press me'),
            dcc.Input(id='inp', value='asdf')
        ]),
        html.Div(id='out', children=[])]
)

@app.callback(
    Output('out', 'children'),
    [Input('btn', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('test', 'children'),
    State('inp', 'value')]
)
def update(n, div, inp):

    print(div)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Yields:

```
[{'props': {'children': 'Press me', 'id': 'btn'}, 'type': 'Button', 'namespace': 'dash_html_components'}, {'props': {'id': 'inp', 'value': 'asdf'}, 'type': 'Input', 'namespace': 'dash_core_components'}]
```

Then upon changing the input and pressing the button:

```
[{'props': {'children': 'Press me', 'id': 'btn', 'n_clicks': 1, 'n_clicks_timestamp': 1542814708494}, 'type': 'Button', 'namespace': 'dash_html_components'}, {'props': {'id': 'inp', 'value': 'hi'}, 'type': 'Input', 'namespace': 'dash_core_components'}]
```

Comment: I'm not actually looking to return the div, I just want to make sure I'm getting it's contents correctly

Comment: Not sure I agree. The way it's set up it effectively returns `None` which for this toy example is fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your issue at first, thanks for clarifying in your edit. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I think this is a bug related to the gotchas here https://dash.plot.ly/faqs